# CRM 2011 import mail workflows set up wrong 'From' field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm having a problem when copying customization between organizations with solution export/import.
That's every time that I copy data between different organizations/environments, I have to go through all workflows and change the references to CRM data, i.e 'From' field of an e-mail, that can be a queue or user mail. 
In the new solution I have "Service" and it should be Service, so having the same name isn't a solution, so I think this is regarding to the GUID of the elements, but there is any option while exporting, I suppose, for avoid that, any freeware tool for that? Thanks!

Comment: Not a fix, but a mitigation approach would be to make sure you only include those workflows in your solution when they have actually changed. I often end up with a solution that holds only workflows so that I can export and import those if, and only if, they change (actually I may have several to hold collections of inter-related workflows), then the main solutions don't 'carry' the workflows across every time.

Comment: Thanks!that's a good point, but the problem comes when I import to a blank organization and must go through all workflows..double work each time..

Comment: If you have a truly *blank* organisation, why not create it the first time round by doing a backup and restore of your database instead, so that it contains all the same records such as queues etc? There is no simple long term fix for this, really.

Comment: but the problem then will be that I'll have all which I didn't want, i.e all Cases and Users that are not for this organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution requires some .Net development, but once it is set up is pretty extensible. Either create a Configuration entity that only ever has one record or create an xml web resource that that stores all the environment variables like references to users, server settings url, etc.

To access your config entity (or web resource) from a Workflow you can create a simple workflow activity that just returns the first record of the configuration entity.  Once you have it you can reference any property on it and since the data in that configuration is a record it unique to that environment.

Like I mentioned you can probably use an XML resource to do it, but retrieving an entity is easier, and you get the CRM UI for option sets and lookups and you can restrict who can edit it with security.  You can also add new fields at any time and not ever have to change your WF activity code.

Comment: I haven't try still, but seems very comprehensible, thank you, was the answer was wondering.